# Manipulate adjacent values in numpy 2D Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-image

I have a 2D binary numpy array with a shape of 250,250. The large majority of cells are 0's, but the 1's are often next to each other, because they form shapes in the matrix. Basically the array looks something like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

I want to identify the objects, to do that I want to change the values of ones so that every object has a unique value, with non-zero values only being the same if they are adjacent. So the matrix should look like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 3 3 3 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 3 3 3 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 4 4
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 4 4 4
```

Is there known algorithm that performs this operation? I've searched scikit-image and numpy but I couldn't find any.

Comment: You could try to use opencv's `findContours` method (https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html), and then fill the contours with their index in the returned contours list.

Comment: Yes, this is called connected component labeling. `skimage` has it implemented under the `measure` module with the function `label`. See [the docs for the `skimage.measure` module](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label). I'll write up an answer for you in a sec. Edit: nope no I wont. Either way, the docs are really easy to read and figure out.

Comment: The skimage.measure looks promising, I think I´ll figure it out from here.